# Why does the createDelay function have a max delay argument?

Tags: html5-audio

The createDelay function of the AudioContext for the Web Audio API takes a single float argument that is the max delay possible for the produced delay node:

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var synthDelay = audioCtx.createDelay(5.0);
```

What's the motivation behind specifying a max delay? Why can't the spec just leave that flexible? Does less delay mean less memory / faster results?